# cant call contract instances on my UI

Tags: solidity, web3js, metamask

I want to be able to display the read functions of my contract on a UI.

These are the calls I make to my UI
Those functions work perfectly in the console using node but when i try to call them from my UI it doesnt work

```
contract.methods.sellPrice().call((err, result) => {console.log(result)})       
contract.methods.buyPrice().call((err, result) => {console.log(result)})  
contract.methods.totalSupply().call((err, result) => {console.log(result)})
```

on my UI I use following code to connect to Web3 and to connect to the read functions, but this doesnt work
I updated my Code to this

```
window.addEventListener('load', async () => {
    // Modern dapp browsers...
    if (window.ethereum) {
        window.web3 = new Web3(ethereum);
        try {
            await ethereum.enable();
            var accounts= await web3.eth.getAccounts();
            var option={from: accounts[0] };
            const  contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi,contractAddress);
             const sellPrice = await contract.methods.sellPrice().call((err, result) => { console.log(result) })

        } catch (error) {
            // User denied account access...
            console.log('error');

        }
    }
    // Legacy dapp browsers...
    else if (window.web3) {
        //window.web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
        console.log(3);
        // Fallback to localhost; use dev console port by default...
        const provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/9bee77f147884c73bb2852e269dacece');
        web3 = new Web3(provider);
        // Acccounts always exposed
        web3.eth.sendTransaction({/* ... */});
    }
    // Non-dapp browsers...
    else {
        console.log('Non-Ethereum browser detected. You should consider trying MetaMask!');
    }
});
contract.methods.sellPrice().send(), function(err, result) {
    if(err) {
        console.log(err, 'err');
    } else {
        console.log(result, 'result');
    }
}
```

and why do i get an error : contract is not defined?

Comment: Since you're doing those calls from an `async` function, you can use `await` instead of psasing a callback function. For example, `const sellPrice = await contract.methods.sellPrice().call();`. Regardless of that, you shouldn't be getting "contract is not defined" anywhere in your program, so there's something here that you're not telling us (i.e., either a part of your code which is not present, or this is not the exact error message that you're getting).

Comment: Come down please. If you want to get help here, then mind your manners to begin with. You might not be targeting the person who's trying to help you, but this attitude still isn't healthy if you want them to keep on trying. Second, refer to the comments you've been given, they might actually help you solve your problem. I wrote very explicitly that the exact error message `contract is not defined` doesn't look like something you could get on your code, so either this is not exactly your code, or this is not exactly the error message.

Comment: BTW, after your edit to the question, it is obvious what you're doing wrong, and that is the fact that you're using `contract` outside the scope where it is declared. And just so you know, this problem has nothing to do with Ethereum, Web3 or anything related. It stems from a simple violation of the rules of Javascript!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDITED**

Take a look at [my code here](https://pastebin.com/yuZiy4dn), I'm able to request the **sellPrice, buyPrice and totalSupply** methods from your smart contract.

Comment: why do i need to send a transaction to get the sellPrice? And what parameters should I pass in there? It doesnt take any. And running it without the parameters and alll of that stuff i get again a contract undefined error

Comment: `sellPrice`, `buyPrice` and `totalSupply` all sound to me like contract methods that are NOT changing the state of the contract. Based on what have you determined otherwise??? This dude even wrote very explicitly at the very top of his question: "I want to be able to display the **read functions** of my contract"... Which pretty much implies that these functions are read-only.

Comment: My bad, don't take my comment as a answer. I just looked at his contract and these 3 functions are view methods ( not changing the state ). https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0xE462CbEE0cd420f6c199B0194B1D8D93Fb5e7720#code This is the code of his smart contract. @CodingJoe next time please attach the link to your smart contract.

Comment: 1. No need to attach links. Just copy/paste the actual code (and only the part relevant to the question). 2. I don't quite understand what you mean by "don't take my comment as a answer". What comment??? The answer seems plain wrong, because it makes a false assumption about the problem (being related to calling non-constant functions).

Comment: @CodingJoe edited my answer, please take a look at my code. #goodvibration That's what I just wanted to say man, I misunderstood the problem. Gosh it's not the of world, everyone makes mistakes. Go out for a fresh air : )

Comment: That doesn't answer the problem that this dude is facing - "why do i get an error : contract is not defined?".

Comment: those function calls are working, but why does it not update on account cahnge or when a tranasction iss sent to the contract?

Comment: This helped a lot- so I can use this functions for everything now thats great. Thanks Im coding since about 3 weeks so all these functions etc werent that clear to me at first but Im sure oncce i finish this project i should get most of it. Unfortunatly the documentation sucks ass out there. The documentations on nodeJs are pretty good but rest is  nerve wrecking. Thanks my Man

Comment: i should jsut be able to call the functions with ajax right?

Comment: so far i see this, etherum blockchain is nothing but a database and Erc20 tokens behave also like a database where all the "attributes" of what this ERC20 Token (smartContract ) can do. To me metamask seems like the key between UI(accounts) and the blockchain, therefore Id like to make it all behave like it- once logged in user should be displayed the output of the functions- i dont know if that makes sense-

Comment: @goodvibration if contract variable was not defined and working in my examples the methods were also not gonna work. That was a lame comment of yours.

Comment: 1. I copied that error message ("contract is not defined") directly from the question. 2. Mind your language!

Comment: @CodingJoe like I said earlier your html won't update just like that if you don't place that update html logic inside event listeners in your javascript. In my example I'm executing methods ```sellPrice```, ```buyPrice ``` and ```totalSupply``` only once at page load. You can call them at any time you wish for example as you mentioned on account change. I already showed you how to track account changes in MetaMask in previous question.