# Unhandled Rejection (Error): invalid address web3.js

Tags: web3js

I got above error.
But I can't solve this problem.
I use web3.js 0.20.5 version;

Here's my web3.js code:

```js
var web3js;

export function setupWeb3(){
    if (typeof web3 !== "undefined") {
        web3js = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
        console.log("injecting web3js success");
        } else {
        console.log("Can NOT access to provider...");
        window.alert("can not access to provider");
        return;
    }
}

var test;
var userAccount;

export function CreateInstance() {
    var accountInterval = setInterval(function() {
        if (web3.eth.accounts[0] !== userAccount) {
          userAccount = web3.eth.accounts[0];
        }
      }, 100);
}

export function WriteMessage(message){
const contractAddress = 0xCf054a36e26b1Ce0e8E4Ab0DA831B259F3bf635F;
const contractABI = [
    {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "getHoge",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": false,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "_input",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "setHoge",
        "outputs": [],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    }
]
    web3.eth.getAccounts((error, accounts) => {
        if (error) {
          console.log(error)
          return
        }
        web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.accounts[0];
        alert(web3.eth.defaultAccount);
    });
    ethereum.enable();
    web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.accounts[0];
    alert(web3.eth.defaultAccount);
    test = web3.eth.contract(contractABI).at(contractAddress);
    test.setHoge(Number(message),{from: web3.eth.defaultAccount});  >>>Error invalid address

}
    

export function getMessage() {
    return test.getHoge().call();
}
```

Comment: "I got above error" - by the minimum, state in which line you got this error!

Comment: I added whick line I got this error

Comment: Have you considered that we should by the least know what `alert(web3.eth.defaultAccount)` gives you, and what `test.setHoge` is? I'm only asking because... well, how exactly do you expect us to answer this question? By guessing all of these vital pieces of information???

Comment: BTW, both your calls to `test.setHoge` and `test.getHoge` should be dealt with as asynchronous function calls (i.e., a function which returns a promise, which you should resolve, for example, using `await`).

Comment: Could you tell me simple example?

Comment: and testHoge is a function that writes an arbitrary number to the blockchain.

Comment: Please add the missing information first.

Comment: alert(web3.eth.defaultAccount) just shows me the value of web3.eth.defaultAccount

Comment: Rrrrright... and that value is?

Comment: Yes, web3.eth.defaultAccount is valid.

Comment: that value is my ropsten address,  0x90fdfF26419fB9550A6a55C792B14122E72714DA

Comment: The problems seems to be that you are mixing async code without waiting (or for web3 v0.20 using callbacks).

Comment: How could I solve this? Could you show me fixed code?

Comment: This answer has some code you can use to start interacting with web3 https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/79088